# Zooming whole scen in Flash

Tags: dictionary, adobe, zooming, interactive, scene

I've made a interactive map in Adobe Flash Profesional CS6 and i was wondering if there is a way to zoom in and out. Yes i know convert map in to a symbol and do Mouseevent. MOUSEWHEEL etc...... But this doesnt make the whole scene zoom in. So is there any way to do that? Thank you for answering guys.
so I've tried this:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, MouseZoom) function MouseZoom(e:MouseEvent):void{
if (e.delta > 0)
{
    trace(e.delta);
    Lake_mc.width +=  20
    Lake_mc.height +=  20
}
if (e.delta < 0)
{
    trace(e.delta);
    Lake_mc.width -=  20;
    Lake_mc.height -=  20;
}}
```